# One or more layers failed to draw: [LAYER NAME] There was a problem drawing the shapefile. Drawing aborted

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, map-drawing, file-size

Using ArcMap 10.1 I Merged multiple .shp layers (each with multiple polylines) into one .shp

The resulting layer will not draw, I get the following error message: One or more layers failed to draw: [LAYER NAME] There was a problem drawing the shapefile. Drawing aborted.

I have re-done the merge but have the same problem.  This is a very large layer - is there a size limit? Could it be taking too much memory to draw?

I don't need to see the layer but want to run intersect with it (so that I can calculate the length of the lines in multiple buffers) and that is returning a blank output - I presume because it is failing to draw.

Comment: Shapefiles have a limit of 2^31-2 bytes in the .shp component.  If you have exceeded this, the shapefile is corrupt, and will not draw or process correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect this is the case then.  I can't even see how many rows there are in the attribute table there are too many.  I will think of a work around.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/50264)?

I think once that issue is resolved, you should be able to run the Intersect tool on the layers chosen.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. While links can be used to support your answer or to provide more details there should be at least a summary or an extract in your answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that and tried before posting my question. I suspect it is a size limit issue.